# How to separate phone number and time in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this: `"00:01:07,400-234-09000:05:01,701-080-08000:05:00,400-234-090"`. All contains by time: hh:mm:ss and 9 digits phone number like: 400-234-090. There is no space in between. How can I separate they into two arrays, one contains only phone numbers, the other contains time.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: Have you ever heard of regular expressions ?

Comment: You have an inconsistent comma delimiter. Is that the entire string?

Answer (score 3):

This is the method:

```
let string = '00:01:07,400-234-09000:05:01,701-080-08000:05:00,400-234-090';

const times = [];
const phoneNumbers = [];

while (string.length > 0) {

    times.push(string.substr(0, 8));
    phoneNumbers.push(string.substr(9, 11));

    string = string.substr(20);

}

console.log(times); // [ '00:01:07', '00:05:01', '00:05:00' ]
console.log(phoneNumbers); // [ '400-234-090', '701-080-080', '400-234-090' ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I needed